# Are intermixed Websocket frame types spec conforming / are there implementations which do it?

Tags: websocket, specifications, rfc6455

Is it Websocket spec conforming to send intermixed frame types, e.g. sending a TEXT frame, then a PING frame and then the second frame of a text message (same connection)?

Are there any implementations around which do support this?

Question popped out with this [lua-websockets issue](https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets/issues/96).

Comment: Are you talking about message fragmentation?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.4

Comment: Maybe you can call it that way... Messages are made up 1-n frames, e.g. a text message "foo" may be send as two frames "f", "oo" as payload respectively (even if this seems pretty stupid).

Comment: @gre_gor Thanks! That's it! Ok so this make implementations more tricky.